# Getting rid of space after comma

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
def date_it(month, day, year):
    month= ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'November', 'December')
    d=int(day)
    y=int(year)
    print month[5],d,",",y
```

OUTPUT: June 17 , 2016
**How do I get rid of the space between 17 and , ?**

Comment: Use string concatenations: `"abc" + "def"` => `"abcdef"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use concatenation instead of varargs.

```
print month[5]+" "+str(d)+", "+str(y)
```